# angular-xeditable (e-ng-options and e-ng-readonly)

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have a couple questions about X-editable:

1. For this table Editable Row: https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row
   When click "`edit`" on a row, how can I modify the code (`e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses"`) so under Status it doesn't only show s.text, but also show s.value? So it will display "1, status1" "2, status2", etc.
2. How can I make a dropdown read-only or disabled? I tried to use e-ng-readonly (`<span editable-select="user.status" e-name="status" e-form="rowform" e-ng-readonly=true e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">`), but it only works for text area, not dropdown. It looks to be greyout and disabled, but actually it still works.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack-overflow Refer :-  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For the first question, you want to get options as status1, status2 etc instead of 1, status1, 2, status2 right??

Comment: No, actually I want to do options as "s.value - s.text", so on a list it should look like:
1 - status1
2 - status2
3 - status3

I think I can create another field in the array to concatenate these two fields (e.g. s.value + ' - ' + s.text) and display that on the option list. But I wonder if there's a better way to do it, and do it with Angular.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24681568/95735

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, use can use the e-ng-disabled="true" directive. And make sure that there's only one object in your 'statuses' array ~ the object in the array being the only object you want to dispaly in the readonly/disabled select box. If you do so, i believe the e-ng-readonly="true" will also work.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around by:
1) introducing a third field called combined. s.combined = s.value + ' | ' + s.text, and displaying s.combined.
2) using ng-if and a flag "isEditable". Only if ng-if="isEditable", use X-editable code. If not, just display the value of the field e.g. {{ showGroup(user) }}  - not editable.